# How can I set the RewriteCond for the exact URL only?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-proxy, proxypass

I need to make a hidden redirect from `sitename.dom` to `sitename.dom2` keeping the rest of string untouched.

For now I use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.dom
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sitename.dom2/$1 [P]
```

and it works perfectly. But. Due to multilanguage on my website the frontpage has the following path:

```
sitename.dom2/lang
```

thats why when user calls *sitename.dom* he is being redirected (hidden) to *sitename.dom2/* and he's getting 404 page.

So, please advise how do I make a strict redirect for exact request only *sitename.dom* without any further?

I had tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.dom$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sitename.dom2\/lang [P]
```

with no luck.

BTW, inside the website language subpath doesn't affect at all. `sitename.dom/lang/page` works as good as `sitename.dom/page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the single redirect before all other. And use dom2 instead of dom1 in this rule.

Here is the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect front page only:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.dom2$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sitename\.dom2$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/sitename\.dom2/\lang" [L]

#redirect all other pages:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.dom2
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sitename\.dom1\/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `/lang` in your first `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.dom$
RewriteRule ^ http://sitename.dom2/lang%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I guess I tried something like that before. Now I'm getting 404 both on citename.dom and citename.dom/lang. Can't get to front page